# Prayer room in Doha International Airport within departure area

Tags: airports, religion, doh

Can we access prayer room in Doha International Airport within the departure area?

Comment: What do you mean by "the boarding area"? The area beyond security? An individual gate?

Comment: IIRC there are plenty in departures but none in the individual gate holding areas

Comment: Sorry, i meant the departure area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a prayer room on your left [as you come into the departure area](http://dohahamadairport.com/airport-guide/at-the-airport/maps).  If you get to Gate B1, you've gone too far.